# How to save a list of Gensim LDA models?

Tags: python, list, save, gensim

I have different LDA models (on the same text, but all with different #topics) stored in one list. Now, I want to save this list with all the models in it to my disk. However, I am not sure how this works. Should I treat is as a list or as a LDA model?

On the [gensim website](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.save) I found the following code:

```
from gensim.test.utils import datapath
>>>
>>> # Save model to disk.
>>> temp_file = datapath("model")
>>> lda.save(temp_file)
```

However, this works for separate LDA models, not for lists with multiple models. What is the best way to save my list of models?

Comment: save it with different filenames?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say `trained_models` is your list of LDA models:

```
trained_models = 
[<gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel at 0x1f321825668>,
 <gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel at 0x1f32181ffd0>]
```

You can save multiple files at once with a for loop and counter:

```
i = 1
for model in trained_models:
    model.save("model{}.gensim".format(i))
    i += 1
```

I don't know of a gensim function that does this, but if there's a more efficient way to do this, I'd love to know as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to save models or sklearn [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as far as loop efficiency I think that's about the most. :)